# Looking up from a list

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel I would like to assign a name to a number based on a separate lists. Example, I have a part number in A1, in D1 I have a title and below it (D2-D11) I have a list of part numbers, in E1 I have another title with a list of part numbers below it, I want the formula in B1 to return the correct title based on what list the part number is in.  Thanks for your help

```
  A        B      C     D          E
1 04     FORMULA       Title   Other Title
2                        01        100
3                        02        101
4                        03        102
5                        04        103
6                        05        105
7                        06        106
8                        07        107
9                        08        108
10                       09        109 
11                       10        110
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The function `COUNTIF` provides a solution:
`=IF(COUNTIF(D2:D11,A1)>0,D1,IF(COUNTIF(E2:E11,A1)>0,E1,"N/A"))`.
Basically, you are first checking if the list in column D contains the criteria A1 (at least once). If so, return the title in D1, if not, perform the same check with column E.

Alternatively you could create a new table which maps each part to its corresponding list name (assuming each part only occurs in one list). Then you could easily use `VLOOKUP` on that table.

Note that if you want to copy this formula to cells B2 to B11 you need to (re)name cells used to define the data ranges (`D2:D11`and `E2:E11`), e.g. `d_begin:d_end` and `e_begin:e_end`.